# Portfolio app for iPhone

Tags: images, ios, iphone-app

I sometimes want to show people design work I've created and all I've got with me is my iPhone. But my camera roll is so full of photos it's hard to find a single image quickly. So there's really no point in storing portfolio work in my camera roll. When I move my photos onto my computer the images would disappear along with the photos. And maybe there is some workaround I could do with photo albums (I'm open to hearing what works for you guys), but I think the best solution would be an app that lets me pull up only the images I've saved to the app, and allow zooming and swiping through those images quickly.

If the app can also store video and audio files this would be a plus, although not absolutely necessary at this time. I don't think such an app would need to be very complex, so I'm hoping a free app like this exists.

All my searches have thus far only turned up portfolio apps for iPad, but I'm looking for an iPhone solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found an app that seems to work well for this. It's designed to keep photos and videos private, so a 4-digit password is required each time to view the content, but I don't mind typing it.

It's called **Private Photo Vault**.

[image: Private Photo Vault in the iPhone App Store]

Comment: You resorted to implementing a photo vault to segregate your images? Does using an album within your photo app not suffice?

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow I did - based on my understanding that an iOS photo album will still have its photos removed if in the Mac Photos app they are copied over to the Mac and then deleted from the iOS device after copying. (If I am wrong in my understanding, please correct me.) Since I wanted just those images to be immune to deletion when transferring my Camera Roll, I went with this option. I'm still open to suggestions, and that's why I have not yet accepted my own answer.